# Is my proof that the monotone convergence theorem implies the Archimedean property correct?

Tags: analysis

I have proved that the monotone convergence theorem implies the nested interval property and now I came up with a "proof" that the monotone convergence theorem implies the Archimedean property.

Assume towards a contradiction that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above. Since $a_{n}=n$ is monotonic by the monotone convergence theorem, $a_{n}$ converges to some $\alpha$. Let $\epsilon = 1$. Then there exists some natural number $N_{1}$ such that $\forall n \ge N_{1}$ implies $|a_{n} - \alpha| < 1$. So look at the term $a_{N_{1}}$ which is really $N_{1}$,we have $|N_{1} - \alpha| < 1$ meaning $\alpha < 1 + N_{1}$. But we assumed that the natural numbers converge to $\alpha$ so it can't be less than the natural number $1+N_{1}$. I have a feeling this proof is wrong, but I am on the right idea.

Comment: Unclear. You introduce $a_n$ and $x$ and $N$  without defining  what they are.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I apologize, I hope the edits made the proof clear.

Comment: "$|N_1-\alpha|<1$ meaning  $\alpha < 1+N_1$". Say "implying", not "meaning". In everyday sppeech you can say "means" when you mean "implies". In this subject it is better to be as precise as possible.

Comment: You are almost done.... $\forall n\in \Bbb N\,(n>1+N_1\implies n\ge 2+ N_1=1+(1+N_1)>1+(\alpha)\implies |n-\alpha|>1,$ contrary to $\forall n>N_1\,(|n-\alpha|<1).$

Comment: BTW. The monotone convergence  property and the Archimedean property are not trivial nor self-evident but are consequences of the definition of $\Bbb R.$ We can define a larger  arithmetic field  $R^*$  with $R^*\supset \Bbb R$ and where $R^*$ has "numbers" that are larger than all $r\in \Bbb R$. And their reciprocals are positive and less than any $r\in \Bbb R^+.$  But in $R^*$  the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ has a positive lower bound in $ R^*$ but no $glb$ in $R^*$, which is terribly inconvenient.